# Why won't my python script work? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pingdom'

Tags: python, rhel, pingdom

So, me and my team uses Pingdom for up time monitoring among other things. During our release process Pingdom alerts us that some of our websites are down, which is expected.

I would like to automate the process of pausing the necessary Pingdom checks. I have tried the following methods.

```
curl -X PUT -u 'username:Password' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'App-Key: applicationkey' -d 'paused=true' https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks/2477066
```

And followed a guide on how to do the same thing via a Python script (I have very minimal knowledge of Python).

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import pingdom 
    sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/git-repo/pingdom-cli')
    p = pingdom.Pingdom(username='username', password='password', appkey='applicationkey')
    p.pause_check('2477066')
```

As I said my knowledge is very minimal so I'm sure I've done something obviously wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `import pingdom` use `import pingdomlib` as this is the right name of the library.

```
import sys
import pingdomlib 
...
p = pingdomlib.Pingdom(username='username', password='password', apikey='applicationkey')
...
```

Comment: There is no `pause_check()` function. Check it out in the api and correct it accordingly. https://github.com/KennethWilke/PingdomLib/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pause_check

Comment: Hi @omri_saadon thanks for the reply, I tried switching pingdom to pingdomlib and I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pingdom.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pingdomlib
ImportError: No module named pingdomlib

Comment: Cheers, I'm really showing my inexperience of Python here - Excuse me!

Comment: I've updated my script to this

    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import pingdom
    import pingdomlib
    sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/git-repo/pingdom-cli')     p=pingdomlib.Pingdom(username='username',password='password',appkey='appkey')
    p.pause_check('2238054')

Comment: And I now get the following error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'appkey'

Comment: @jto You should change the `appkey` to `apikey`, for more info see [here](https://github.com/KennethWilke/PingdomLib)

Comment: Woo, thank you! I just need to work on the multi-user authentication section of this script now. You've been a lot of help, thank you!